# Automating rsync commands

Tags: rsync, scripts

I currently have too many `rsync` commands that I run on a day to day basis.
Could someone be kind enough to let me know how I can automate these commands?
I am new to Linux so a little bit of explanation might be needed.

Comment: Any familiarity with cron and/or with shell scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first save the following in a file named `rsynccommands.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "starting all"
rsync-command-1
echo "completed 1"
rsync-command-2
echo "completed 2, starting 3"
rsync-command-3
echo "completed 3, starting 4"
rsync-command-4
echo "completed 4, starting 5"
rsync-command-5
echo "completed 5, completed all."
```

That is a bash script.

Make the script executable:

```
chmod + x /hom/USER/path/to/rsynccommands.sh
```

Then run the command `crontab -e` and copy/paste the following:

```
30 13 * * * /home/USER/path/to/rsynccommands.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

That will run the script every day at 1:30pm, the 30 being 30 mins past and the 13 being 1pm. The stars mean every day, month and year.

Comment: Excellent!!! Bulls Eye!! That's What I was looking for... Many thanks ... I will surely let you know whats the result looks like.... cheers

Comment: Glad to be helpful!

Comment: A Quick Question: Some of my Folders in the Source Directory has a space e.g My Files these folders does not get copied.  Is there a specific way to give the space in the rsync comand? Thanks

Comment: Yep, put the directory in quotes - e.g. `/home/path/to/directory` is fine but `/home/path/to/directory with space` isn't. Instead do `"/home/path/to/directory with space"`

Comment: hi what does "/dev/null 2>&1" this means?

Comment: It redirects the output so that you don't get any messages in terminal. It isn't necessary.

Comment: your instructions worked like a charm! thanks. can I insert "c:\sync.txt" instead of "/dev/null 2>&1" to get a log files created? so that I can go through that to see if sync has been successful or if there are any error?

Comment: No, ubuntu doesn have a `c:\`. You use `/` to be root folder. Do `sync.txt` and it will be in your home area, no \ or /s

Comment: hi time@ my crontab entry only create a empty log files.  It does not do anything.  Here is the sample                       #! /bin/bash

echo "Rsync - MA Inbound Files"
rsync -rvu /media/hdd2/MA-Inbound /media/miracle/
echo "Completed MA Inbound Files Sync, Starting Tally.ERP 9 Data File Sync"
rsync -rvu /media/hdd2/Tally.ERP9 /media/miracle/
echo "Completd Tally.ERP9 Data File Sync, Starting 2011 Accounts Files Sync,"

Comment: Okay, so that isn't needed then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cron](http://ss64.com/bash/crontab.html) to schedule your rsync commands to run on a regular basis.

There is loads of information about cron on the web, but some terms to help you search would be `cron`, `crontab`, `cron job`.

`cron` is the mechanism/software that runs scheduled `cron jobs` as specified in a `crontab` file.

To edit your crontab sun `crontab -e`. Each user on a system has their own crontab, you can edit the root user's crontab  by using `sudo crontab -e` if your job needs elevated privilege.

There is also a general crontab at `/etc/crontab` where you can specify which user to run the job as.

Ussually you want to stick with only editing your own crontab.

A sample cron entry to run an rsync script every day at 5am would look like:

```
5 * * * *   rsync command here > logfile.txt
```

`5 * * * *` Means the 5th hour, of every day, of every week, any day of the month, and day of the week

`rsync command here` Is obviously your `rsync` command. **Use full absolute paths**

`> logfile.txt` Will redirect output to a log file, which my or may not want.

Comment: `5 * * * *   rsync command here > logfile.txt`actually means **5 minutes after every hour** if I am not mistaken. To run this job every at 5am every day, ...., write `00 05 * * *  rsync command here > logfile.txt`.